# C++ time limit for function

Tags: c++, algorithm

im trying to implement a time limit for my negamax alpha beta algorithm, but i can't seem to figure it out. what im trying to achieve is: start calculating a move , if the calculations arent done within 5 seconds, return the best move at this point.

how can i do this?
is it even possible with negamax?

pseudo code for the negamax:

```
01 function negamax(node, depth, α, β, color)
02     if depth = 0 or node is a terminal node
03         return color * the heuristic value of node

04     childNodes := GenerateMoves(node)
05     childNodes := OrderMoves(childNodes)
06     bestValue := −∞
07     foreach child in childNodes
08         v := −negamax(child, depth − 1, −β, −α, −color)
09         bestValue := max( bestValue, v )
10         α := max( α, v )
11         if α ≥ β
12             break
13     return bestValue
```

if needed i can add my c++ implementation of the negamax algorithm

Comment: just check the elapsed time in the loop.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath ok, but how can i make sure i return the current best value after 5 seconds?

Comment: what do you mean by "best value"?

Comment: the matter is already solved, thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difficulty I can see is the recursion, but thats not really a problem, just call it with the current time and in the beginning of each call check if time elapsed is bigger than 5 seconds:

```
01 function negamax(node, depth, α, β, color, startTime)
02     if (currentTime - startTime > 5sec) or depth = 0 or node is a terminal node
03         return color * the heuristic value of node
```

For convenience you can use a wrapper:

```
function negamaxWrap(node, depth, α, β, color)
    return negamax(node, depth, α, β, color, currentTime)
```

How to make sure that you got the best value? When the stack is unwinded the returned value will still pass the test:

```
bestValue := max( bestValue, v )
```

thus you will get the `max` of the values found so far.

Comment: does this also mean that the returned node is the best node it has currently discovered?

Comment: @user3499284 added one more sentence

Comment: amazing, i will try this.

Comment: @user3499284 btw what is that algorithm good for? Never heard of it before

Comment: its an ai  algorithm, used to determine the best move on games like tic tac toe, hex, chess, etc. you can use it in combination with monte carlo to calculate the best move if the game is too complex to calculate all possible options.  The good thing is that this algorithm also looks at the best moves for your opponent.